# Polymer core-ajax PUT 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, polymer

So basically I have an element that has a text area within it. I want to be able to save the inputted text to a loaded into a JSON file. I keep getting a 405 (Method not allowed). Page plus JSON all within the same domain.

**Note:** I am very new to this so I am unsure if this is even possible. Cheers

```
<paper-input-decorator id="input_box"hidden >
        <paper-autogrow-textarea style="width:100%">
            <textarea id="noteArea"></textarea>
        </paper-autogrow-textarea>
</paper-input-decorator>

<core-ajax 
   auto
   id="save"
   url="{{url}}"
   method="PUT"
   params='{"id":"{{id}}", "note":"{{note}}"}'
   handleas="json"
   on-core-response="{{handleResponse}}">
</core-ajax>

<script>
    Polymer("add-note", {
        open: function (event, detail, sender) {
            this.$.input_box.hidden = !this.$.input_box.hidden;
            this.note = this.$.noteArea.value;
            this.$.save.go();
        },
        handleResponse: function (response) {
            console.log(response, this.url, this.uid);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Json Data looks something like this

```
[
    {
    "uid": 1,
    "note":  ""
    }
]
```

Hope all that help. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going through your code, and there are certain things that I dont know about.

in Line `params='{"id":"{{id}}", "note":"{{note}}"}'` Where is the value of `{{id}}` coming from?

where are you calling the `open` function?

And the reason you might be getting `405` error code, because the webservice you are trying to call might not support `PUT` method at all. You might need to confirm it from the person who worked on the webservice.

Also `this.note = this.$.noteArea.value;` might not be a good way of assigning the value. Try looking into two way data binding in Polymer.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the time. id is coming from the attributes. This sits within a element that is created automatically through repeat. Not to worry now though. This is changing